# Unity Webgl Проблема с туманом

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет. При билде под web вылазят такие гличи с туманом(со светом).
**Unity 2022.3.8**
Туман - **gamma, exponential**.
Свет - все динамика.
**Без тумана гличей нет.**
Менял настройки качества для билда - результат 0.
В сцене используются 3 камеры - (depth -1 - только небо(depth only), 1 - все кроме некоторыx партиклов(depth only), 2 - партиклы(depth only)).
В индексе "config['webglContextAttributes'] = {"preserveDrawingBuffer": true};" прописал.
**Кто нибудь может подсказать, в чем может быть проблема?**

[image: скрин]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в камерах. В rendering path - нужно было выставить у всех use graphics settings или deffered. Forward не поддерживается для webgl .net framework 2.1  в unity.